# Trimming empty elements off end of byte array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, trim

I am doing some network programming with UDP and am trying to break down a large packet into many smaller packets and then send them across the network. Everything works great until it is time for the last packet to be sent. The problem with the last packet is that it that the associated byte[] has some trailing space at the end because the byte[] is always 1024 bytes, but the loop only fills the array when there is still file data to be sent. What is the best way to remove the empty elements of the byte[] before putting the array in a DatagramPacket to be sent across the network?

```
    while(count < fileData.length) {
            for(int i=0; i<smallBuffSize; i++){
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println(fileData.length);
                if(count < fileData.length){
                    data[i] = fileData[count];
                    count++;
                }
            }

            DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, serverAddress, 5000); 
            socket2.send(dataPacket);
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean `Arrays.copyOf(bytes, length)` ?

Comment: Well I had no idea there was such a thing, but that worked wonderfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `data.length` as the length when there is not this much data, I suggest just providing the actual length.  This way there won't be any padding of the data at the end.

Comment: Well this is just a simple case for the basic structure. Usually there will be much more and it is variable depending on what file they upload.

Comment: @Xerunix in which case, I suggest you use a variable to determine the length.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realize you were the same person that left the comment on the main post. Yeah that is exactly what I ended up doing. And then I used the variable to determine how big of a copy to make. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Xerunix on the sending side, you don't need to take a copy, when you create the DatagramPacket, you just say how much of the byte[] you want to use.

Comment: Good point. I adjusted the code accordingly. DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, dataLength, serverAddress, 5000);      Still only works for text files for some reason so I'll keep debugging, but I appreciate the help.